# IPMI hardware monitor on ASUS Bios shows N/A for all sensors

Tags: asus, system-monitoring, ipmi

I have an "ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI" motherboard. The IPMI Hardware Monitor in BIOS displays a list of sensors for temperature, voltage, and fan speed, but all of them show 'N/A' instead of actual readings..

When I use ipmitool in OS on the same machine, for all the sensors it reports either "no reading", "Not Readable" or zero.

Comment: Have you tried updating the [BMC firmware](https://www.asus.com/us/motherboards-components/motherboards/workstation/pro-ws-wrx80e-sage-se-wifi/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=Pro-WS-WRX80E-SAGE-SE-WIFI)?